# Make two table beside each other

Tags: css

I want my `table` **Semester Attended** to be in the left of the **Grade** `table`. How can i achieve this? Im new to html and css. Can someone give me clues to achieve this?

[image]

here's my code.

```
         <div class="table-responsive">
         <table  class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Semester Attended</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <aside></aside>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>


        <div class="table-responsive">
       <div id="gradetable">

       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do the HTML/CSS tutorial on https://www.codecademy.com/ and you will understand how to do that afterwards.

Comment: share the full code..

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap - just use the grid system. Create new row, add to columns (`.col-X-6`), and inside each column's-cell put one table.

Comment: @Dekel How can i mark your answer as a correct answer?

Comment: Well, you can't, because it's only a comment. But I can add this as an answer :)

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap - just use the grid system.
Create new row, add to columns (.col-X-6), and inside each column's-cell put one table.

Something like that:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table  class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Semester Attended</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <aside></aside>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <div id="gradetable">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap both tables for each column, same row in another table.

**E.g.**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Semester Attended Table</th>
      <th>Grade Table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <table id="semesterAttendedTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Semester 1</td>
            <td>Semester 2</td>
            <td>Semester 3</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 1,1</td>
            <td>Row 1,2</td>
            <td>Row 1,3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 2,1</td>
            <td>Row 2,2</td>
            <td>Row 2,3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>

      <table id="gradeTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Grade 1</td>
            <td>Grade 2</td>
            <td>Grade 3</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 1,1</td>
            <td>Row 1,2</td>
            <td>Row 1,3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 2,1</td>
            <td>Row 2,2</td>
            <td>Row 2,3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tbody>
  </table
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add float:left to the div with the first table.

```css
div.semester {
    float:left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive semester">
         <table  class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Semester Attended</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <aside></aside>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive" id="gradetable">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Grades</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <aside></aside>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```